# How to pass a URL parameter to jersey web service like ...?lib=T%E2che%20Yves

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jersey, special-characters, url-parameters

I have a web service that receives a parameter with special characters encoded in hexadecimal values.

```
@PUT
@Path("/tasks")
@Produces("application/xml; charset=UTF-8")
public Response createTask( @QueryParam("lib")
String pLibelle) {

    logger.debug(" -> lib =" + pLibelle);
...
```

With the following lib parameter:

```
http://webservice.com/tasks?lib=T%E2che%20Yves
```

The debugger displays:

```
-> lib =T?che Yves
```

But I was expecting

```
-> lib =T%E2che%20Yves
```

Or if my dreams came true I could have:

```
-> lib =Tâche Yves
```

(that's the original string before URL encoding)

So my question is: 
How can I get my original string? It seems that the URL-encoded parameter is already traduced in a wrong way by the Jersey mechanism, and i seem to have no control on it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When URL encoded, `Tâche Yves` should be `T%C3%A2che%20Yves` and not `T%E2che%20Yves`.

Observe the following:

- When using UTF-8, `â` is encoded as `%C3%A2`.
- When using CP-1252, `â` is encoded as `%E2`.

---

You can use the [`@Encoded`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Encoded.html) annotation to get the value URL encoded:

```java
@PUT
@Path("/foo")
@Produces("application/xml; charset=UTF-8")
public Response method(@Encoded @QueryParam("bar") String bar) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cássio Mazzochi Molin!

Answer (score 0):

That's the final code I'll be using:

```java
@PUT
@Path("/tasks")
@Produces("application/xml; charset=UTF-8")
public Response createTask(@Encoded @QueryParam("lib") String pLibelleUrlIso8859_1) {

    String lLibelleIso8859_1 = "";
    String lLibelleUtf8 = "";

    try {

        // Conversion 1 : (ISO-8859-1 + URLEncoded) -> ISO-8859-1
        lLibelleIso8859_1 = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(pLibelleUrlIso8859_1, "ISO-8859-1");

        // Conversion 2 : ISO-8859-1 -> UTF-8
        lLibelleUtf8 = javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.decodeText(lLibelleIso8859_1);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

        logger.error("[createTask] " + e1.getMessage());

        // ERROR 500 - A038
        lOutput = erreurXml("A038", 
                            "Unsupported encoding. ISO-8859-1 + URL Encoding expected.", 
                            e1);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                       .entity(lOutput).build();
    }

    logger.debug(" -> lib =" + pLibelleUtf8);

    ...
}
```